# .htaccess redirection issue in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a coupon site in a sub-folder like
yoursitename.com/coupons and we are using these contents in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /coupons
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^coupons/category/(.*)$ /coupons/category.php?c=$1 [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^coupons/store/(.*)$ /coupons/stores.php?c=$1 [R=301,NC,P]
```

as we want to redirect:

```
yoursitename.com/coupons/store/StoreName
```

to:

```
yoursitename.com/coupons/stores.php?c=StoreName
```

We had tried `RewriteBase /` but this too doesn't work.

We have a .htaccess file in root folder also that does some other tasks or renaming extention but that is working perfectly fine, so don't have any idea why this one is not working.

Comment: Enable and check the `RewriteLog` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /coupons/

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /coupons/category.php?c=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ /coupons/stores.php?c=$1 [NC]
```

If you declare the RewriteBase as `/coupons/` you need to remove it from your RewriteRules. Your RewriteRules will start right after the RewriteBase.

Also you don't want it to be a redirection, just an internal rewriting so you shall not put `R=301` flag. The `P` flag is also useless here.